Как закруглить полую кнопку?
У меня есть кнопка
Margin="362,19,30,19" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" FontFamily="Segoe UI" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#3F3F90" Content="Зарегестрироваться">

Я ее округлил с помощью
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border Background="#3F3F90" CornerRadius="3">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>

Однако, из-за этого, она перестала быть полой
Под "Полой", Я подразумеваю, что у нее видны только края и текст (Для этого я и установил Background="Transparent")
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Может хотяб скриншот приложите, чтоб было понятно о чем речь?

Ладно, пришлось запускать студию, копировать код, чистить его, запускать. смотреть... На будущее, пожалуйста, не заставляйте людей делать лишние телодвижения. Касательно вопроса, вы ведь сами пишете внутреннему Border фон, уберите его и будет вам "полая". P.S. Вот это Margin="362,19,30,19" ужас, который говорит сразу о том, что у вас не так написана разметка.

Вам надо указать толщину бордера

@EvgeniyZ Не сочтите за предьяву, но перед тем как писать ответ на вопрос, проверяйте, тем более раз уж запустили студию условно. Если убрать фон бордера, то пропадут и края и текст(По крайней мере в моем случае). Я подозреваю, это потому что бордер находится как "слой" над кнопкой.

Я ответа не писал, а лишь попросил дать больше информации (чего вы не сделали). Прежде чем кидаться такими "предьявами", поймите что от вас просят, что хотят, и что надо сделать. Также поймите как работает ресурс и что такое "комментарий". Не в наших интересах запускать студию ради того, чтоб дописать ваш код, проверить что не так, воспроизвести проблему, написать на основе этого ответ.  Также, что в вопросе? "она перестала быть полой" - почему она перестает быть полой? Потому что вы указали задний фон. А вот то, что там "пропадают" - это есть в вопросе? Нет. К чему тогда эти предъявы?

@EvgeniyZ "Касательно вопроса, вы ведь сами пишете внутреннему Border фон, уберите его и будет вам "полая"." Что это, как не "Сделайте так, и у вас все получится"? А на счет того что я не предоставил скринов и вам упаси господь пришлось ВКЛЮЧИТЬ Вижуал студио, ну простите пожалуйста, впредь буду стараться не обременять вас такими сложностями)

Надеюсь на то, что впредь от вас будут идти более качественные вопросы. Удачи!

Другим пользователям, дай бог им здоровья, хватило и такого, уродливого, абсолютно непонятного и ужасно непрофессионального вопроса, чтобы понять, что такое "Полая" кнопка. И вам удачи!

BorderBrush и BorderThickness
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>

Документация

@aepot Помогло! Спасибо вам большое!
